# Modify ls output to display [+] in front of directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, ls

I am looking for a way to modify the **ls** output in that way that every directory displays **[+]** in front of the directory name. Ideally doing via bashrc.

```
me@computer[~]$ ls 
[+]directory           [+]directory 
[+]directory           file.png
file                   file.txt 
readme
```

Currently I am just customizing the color output:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;37;4' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Comment: There is an option that already does *almost* what you want: `ls -F` appends different symbols to different file types, like `/` to directories, `*` to executable files, `@` for symbolic links and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, but it gives you only one column output:

```
ls | sed -r "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d/ -f2 | sed "1 d; 2~1 { s:.*:s/^\\(&\\)$/[+]\\\\1/;:g}")"
```

It works by piping the output of `ls` through `sed` and the sed script is dynamically build using a pipe that converts a list of directories to a list of `S/^dirname$/[+]dirname/;` sed script lines.

Just try out all the parts individually to see how it works.

For example when run in /etc the outputs starts likes this:

```
[+]acpi
adduser.conf
[+]adobe
[+]akonadi
aliases
aliases.db
```

You might want to alias the command in your bashrc.

And you might want to look into the `tree` command.

Comment: pipe to column can be added

Comment: You can force column output with `-C`, but because the length of individual words is changed, it might mess up the tab alignment.

Comment: This will fail, like all attempts to parse the output of `ls`, if a file name contains a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

`ls -l`   : directories will start with d.
`ls -p`   : a slash will be added into directory name like dir/
`ls -F`   : will also add a slash after dir names and other marks to other file types (*, etc)
`ls -d */` : As advised in comments, will list only dir names with a slash at the end. Remove -d to see also sub dir contents.

In terms of manipulating ls output you could go like :

```
ls -l |awk '/^d/{print "[+]"$NF}; /^[^d]/{print $NF}' |column
```

You can also use `find` and avoid parsing `ls` since had been said that parsing ls might break if file names contain strange chars like new lines etc.
`find` in this format will produce output identical to above `ls`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Y %f\n' |awk '/^d/{print "[+]"$NF}; /^[^d]/{print $NF}' |column
```

Comment: NIce. And much more elegant than what I came up with.

Comment: If you only want to see directories, use `ls */`; no need to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: @chepner Good tip. Just for the record, `ls */` will expand also dir contents and the screen becomes messy. Can be restricted with `ls -d */` to display only dir names.

Comment: @LarsFischer Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should also try this using a bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myls() {
    for i in *;do
        [[ -d "${i}" ]]  && {
             printf "%s\n" "[+] ${i}"
             continue;
        }
        printf "%s\n" "${i}"
    done
}
```

source the script in your `.bashrc` file. Whenever you want to use this, just call `myls` in the directory.

you should note that it does not give you a colored output